# ColdFusion Illudium PU-36 Code Generator

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion

When generating models from postgresql with ColdFusion Illudium Code generator the boolean values get converted to varchar in the cfqueryparam and varchar gets converted to char. Does anyone have a fix for this issue?

http://cfcgenerator.riaforge.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.open the file cfcgenerator/com/cf/model/datasource/postgresql.cfc
 2.around line 63 replace bit/bool with this

```
    <!--- bit / bool --->
        <cfcase value="bit,boolean">
            <cfreturn "cf_sql_bit" />
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="bool">
            <cfreturn "cf_sql_varchar" />
        </cfcase>
```

3.around line 101 replace strings with this

```
<!--- strings --->
        <cfcase value="char">
            <cfreturn "cf_sql_char" />
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="varchar,character varying,character">
            <cfreturn "cf_sql_varchar" />
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="text">
            <cfreturn "cf_sql_longvarchar" />
        </cfcase>
```

Comment: The cfcgenerator is a great tool, highly configurable.  +1 for a nice answer from a new guy ;) Welcome to stackoverflow.